# Scenario based questions in Datastage

Tags: datastage

I have two scenario based questions here.

**Question 1**

**Input Dataset**

Col1

A

A

B

C

C

B

D

A

C

**Output Dataset**

Col1 Col2

A     1

A     2

A     3

B     1

B     2

C     1

C     2

C     3

D     1

**Question2**

Input data string
AA-BB-CC-DD-EE-FF (can be of any delimiter and string can have any length)

Output data string
string 1 -> AA

string 2 -> BB

string 3 -> CC

string 4 -> DD

Thanks & Regards,
Subhasree

Comment: Two questions - please open two separate questions - this will result in appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: Can be solved with a transformer. Sort the data and use the [lastrowingroup](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZJPZ_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.parjob.dev.doc/topics/detectingkeybreaks2.html) functionality. 
For Col2 just create a counter as a stage variable and add 1 for each row - if reset it with a second stage variable if lastrowingroup is reached.
Aternatively you could use a rownumber column in SQL.

Question2: You have not provided enough information. Is string1 a column or row? If you do not know anything upfront about the structure (any delimiter) this will get hard...